# core-ajax accessing firebase data created with push()

Tags: firebase, polymer

When first building my app, I had manually created data and it looked similar to this:

```
{
  "data": {
    0: {
      "author": "gracehop",
      "title": "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    },
    1: {
      "author": "alanisawesome",
      "title": "The Turing Machine"
    }
  }
}
```

I could retrieve the data using core-ajax and iterate through a custom component without problem, like this:

```
  <template is="auto-binding">
        <core-ajax id="ds" auto url="https://mysite.firebaseio.com/data.json" response="{{data}}"></core-ajax>
        <my-items items="{{data}}"></my-items>
  </template>
```

However, now I'm attempting to create new data in my app using push().  The problem is that the new data looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": {
      "author": "gracehop",
      "title": "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    },
    "-JRHTHaKuITFIhnj02kE": {
      "author": "alanisawesome",
      "title": "The Turing Machine"
    }
  }
}
```

This lines up with [their documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html), which states

> Your first instinct might be to use set() to store children with
>   auto-incrementing integer indexes ... Firebase provides a push()
>   function that generates a unique ID every time a new child is added to
>   the specified Firebase reference. By using unique child names for each
>   new element in the list, several clients can add children to the same
>   location at the same time without worrying about write conflicts. The
>   unique ID generated by push() is based on a timestamp, so list items
>   will automatically be ordered chronologically.

After pushing an item or two, I no longer see any items in my list.  If I delete anything created using push() the other items show up again.

Comment: You tagged this with 'Polymer' but I'm not seeing any Polymer codez...

Comment: Firebase `push` creates maps not arrays, and `template repeat` only consumes arrays. You'll have to create an intermediate array or iterate over keys.

Comment: That is by the way exactly what Firebase's AngularFire does for Angular: when you cal `$asArray()` it constructs an array out of the ordered collection that Firebase uses normally. (see https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/tree/master/src if you feel up to the challenge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `core-ajax` element, you should be using the native `firebase-element`. You can then connect it with your data by assigning the `location` attribute to your unique Firebase URL, then access the data with the `data` attribute. Likewise, if you are interested in looping through your data, you will need to access the `keys` attribute since Polymer currently only iterates through arrays.

Your firebase element would look something like this:

```
<firebase-element id="base" location="https://YOUR.firebaseio.com/" 
   data="{{data}}" keys="{{keys}}"></firebase-element>
```

You would then access it like so:

```
<template repeat="key in keys">
   <p>This is your uniqueId generated keys: {{keys}}</p>
   <p>This is the data in the keys: {{data[key]['author']}}</p>
</template>
```

Here is the ref: http://polymer.github.io/firebase-element/components/firebase-element/

Answer (score 1):

The items are not missing or deleted. Indeed if you check out your account dashboard, you'll see both the numeric indices and the push ids. What happens is related to [Firebase's handling of array-like data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase). (You'll want to give that a serious read to understand this)

Essentially, since you've used sequential, numeric ids, the data is treated as an array and returned as an array. But when you add a string as a key, it decides this is now a hash of key/value pairs and treats it as pojo/json data (rightly so).

I don't know much (anything) about Polymer, but I'm guessing that method accepts an array and does not iterate object keys. Thus, you'll need to iterate that data as an object and not an array.